# Unable to run time.php

Tags: php, apache, localhost

my php file has the following simple code :
The time is

```
<?php echo date(‘H:i:s’);?>
```

and the date is

```
<?php echo date(‘j F Y’);?>
```

But i am getting the following error on typing the command :
http://localhost/time.php

```
404 Not Found
An error occured trying to access document or resource /time.php.
Please contact the server administrator if the problem is abnormal and persists.
```

But m unable to sort out the error .m a beginner for php .plz help .os is ubuntu 10.04 n i have anstalled apache2 n php5.

Comment: Does navigating to just `localhost` work? What about `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: are you running XAMPP or any other local webserver software? It looks like you're local machine is not a webserver.

Comment: This means that the file is not in the correct location. You need to make sure you are working in localhost's webroot. If you don't know the exact path to it, you can find out in the server configuration (usually httpd.conf or httpd.vhosts.conf)

Comment: yes on typing simply http://localhost  it displays it works message !

Comment: A 404 indicates that the server is running but there is no time.php in the web root for Apache.

Comment: @pekka ....hw can i find out the exact path .Earlier everything worked out well but after restarting my system ...this simple file is not working

Comment: @alen hw can i find out webroot for apache.my os is UBUNTU 10.04

Comment: Check your httpd.conf or apache2.conf file and make sure you set the DocumentRoot setting to your public folder (usually "/var/www").

Comment: check apache error_log, it should able to indicate what is the 404 about, usually is DocumentRoot related

Comment: this is my current error.log file :

Comment: [Tue Nov 09 12:39:13 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 09 12:39:19 2010] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Tue Nov 09 12:39:19 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 09 12:39:24 2010] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Comment: i found this in /var/log/apache2

Answer (score 0):

The `404` error indicates that your `time.php` file is not located in the root  directory that Apache is running from.

Most likely you will need to move `time.php` into a `public_html` or `htdocs` folder.

In Ubuntu, this is usually located in `/var/www/apache2-default/`

If you look around in `/var/www/` you will probably find a index.html file that contains the "It Works" message. Place your `time.php` in the same directory as that file.

Comment: @alan where can i find the folders mentioned by u ?

Comment: Look into `/var/www`, that's a common place.

Comment: there is no folder named apache2-default in /var/www

Comment: What folders do you see under `/var/www/`?  As others have mentioned, this is an Apache configuration issue and without seeing your configuration we cannot help much.  But if you look around in `/var/www/` you will probably find a `index.html` file that contains the "It Works" message.  Place your time.php in the same directory as that file.

Comment: at the same place where index.html is located !

Comment: but there is also a folder named nanoweb. shud i delete this folder ?I really don't know its use !

Comment: in /www there is only one folder named as nanoweb . I don't know about its use .

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the problem, open the httpd file, usually located in

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Find DocumentRoot - check what folder is your document root. In this folder, you can execute your PHP file. Did you install PHP on your server, local machine?

Comment: @Max there is no folder named httpd in /etc

Comment: but i have this file named httpd.conf in the folder /etc/apache2.

Comment: but however in the path mentioned above the file httpd.conf i totally empty .It is of zero bytes

Comment: Check out  ... /etc/apache2 folder .. find httpd.conf file What OS are you ?

Comment: can you post what DocumentRoot folder is ?

Comment: ok I see the problem ,in /etc/apache2 folder go to sites-enabled folder , open 000-default file , there is DocumentRoot property

Comment: there is another tag < directory should be the same as DocumentRoot , this is your default server document root , put timer.php there I'm not sure if your php installed , create a new file with .php extension , type in it <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> then in your browser navigate to this file , do you see phpinfo page ?

Comment: on opening the file mozilla asks whether to open the file or save the file . What should I do now ?